# Firebug doesn’t display my javascript? can't find the error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

well I want to debug some script with Firebug, (cause I can't see anything in the browser window) but when I click the script tab in Firefox it gives me the error message:

**If  tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).**

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>



<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
/* fix: “close” the value of i inside createFunction, so it won't change */
        var createFunction = function(i) {
            return function() { alert(i); };
        };

        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            $('p').appendTo('body').on("click", createFunction(i));
}

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IT'S IN black-BOLD! in my text!

Comment: When I run that in my Firefox I get a Firebug error `$(function () {var createFunction = function (i) {return function () {alert(i);};};for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {$("p").appendTo("body").on("click", createFunction(i));}}) is not a function`

Comment: add `type="text/javascript"` to your first `<script>` tag

Comment: <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @KrisIvanov & nbrooks that's not necessary with html5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must leave out the last parenthesis, I guess the code should run on dom ready?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
/* fix: “close” the value of i inside createFunction, so it won't change */
        var createFunction = function(i) {
            return function() { alert(i); };
        };

        for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            $('<p>').appendTo('body').on("click", createFunction(i));
}

});
</script>
```

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for how to make code running on dom load with jquery.

Comment: @acne hey it works! thanks for dat! funny this is an syntax-error that firebug should point out...one more thing why Ican't see any in the browser? P should be append to the body uhn?

Comment: You must use `<p>` when creating elements, otherwise it's just a plain selector for jquery. jQuery searches for an *existing* p element and tries to append that to the body. Because there does not exist one, nothing gets appended. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also worth noting that since you have an HTML5 doctype,  type="text/javascript" is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Remove parenthesis after `})`:

```
$(function() {
/* fix: “close” the value of i inside createFunction, so it won't change */
     var createFunction = function(i) {
        return function() { alert(i); };
     };

     for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            $('p').appendTo('body').on("click", createFunction(i));
     }    
});  //here is the modification
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Case I have opened firebug in other tab, So it was showing me this error.

- Solution : I have closed one tab and refreshed the page. and it was working :)